# How do you create an instance of a class using a function in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop

Something like this:

```
def new_instance(class_name):
    return instance_of_class
```

E.g. if I had a Dog class, I could write `d = new_instance(Dog)` and `d` would now refer to a new Dog object.

Obviously I can write `d = Dog()` but I'd like to pass in the class as a parameter to the init method of another class.

Comment: you're passing the class as a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class is just a named object like any other, so you can pass it as an argument to a function just as easily as you'd pass any other object.

```
def new_instance(cls):
    return cls()
```

```
d = new_instance(Dog)  # same as d = Dog()
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I thought I tried something like this, but apparently I didn't quite get it right!